# Programmatically resizing views to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, view, resize

I know this question may have been answered a few times, however, I've literally tried every possible thing that I could find on StackOverflow, without success.

Basically, I have custom UIView class that I initialize like so:

```
MyUIView *test = [[MyUIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Then, I have a NSTimer scheduled to go off in 5 seconds with this call:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (!self.isRotated) {
        self.isRotated = YES;
        appDelegate.allowLandscape = YES;
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];
    }else{
        self.isRotated = NO;
        appDelegate.allowLandscape = NO;
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait] forKey:@"orientation"];
    }
```

Which basically does:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if (self.allowLandscape) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    }else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

And it works fine if I just set `self.allowLandscape` to `YES` in the `viewDidLoad` method. However, if I call the NSTimer method after 5 second delay, the UIView doesn't get translated into `LandscapeLeft`.

I could probably solve this by using constraints, however, in this project, I'm solely using programmatic sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **[AutoresizingMasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizesSubviews)** like so:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

> This will resize the view automatically according to the superclass.